# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I want to start `mysql` but it doesn't work.

> furnaxe@furnaxe-Inspiron-5593:~$ sudo mysql ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't
> connect to local MySQL server through socket
> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

And this is journaltcl -xe :

```
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) mysql.service a terminé son arrêt.
févr. 05 12:06:43 furnaxe-Inspiron-5593 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickl>
févr. 05 12:06:43 furnaxe-Inspiron-5593 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
févr. 05 12:06:43 furnaxe-Inspiron-5593 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) mysql.service a échoué
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- L'unité (unit) mysql.service a échoué, avec le résultat failed.
févr. 05 12:07:17 furnaxe-Inspiron-5593 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1708]: (EE) event9  - DELL097C:0>
févr. 05 12:07:17 furnaxe-Inspiron-5593 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1708]: See https://wayland.freed>
```

I think I have some missing packages.
Then:

```
furnaxe@furnaxe-Inspiron-5593:~$ systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-02-05 12:06:43 CET; 10min ago
    Process: 20009 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAIL>

févr. 05 12:06:43 furnaxe-Inspiron-5593 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart co>
févr. 05 12:06:43 furnaxe-Inspiron-5593 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
févr. 05 12:06:43 furnaxe-Inspiron-5593 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickl>
févr. 05 12:06:43 furnaxe-Inspiron-5593 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
févr. 05 12:06:43 furnaxe-Inspiron-5593 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I already tried to uninstall mysql and reinstall it with the `sudo apt purge mysql*` and `sudo rm -r /etc/mysql` and `sudo rm -r /usr/share/mysql`.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Look at the error logs

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't understand what I have to do and that's why I made this post.

Comment: `journalctl -n 30 -u mysql.service`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QSbgrYcq

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Qc0nTSDV for the error.log in /var/log/mysql